# Show banner notifications even in full screen

Tags: notifications, ventura, fullscreen

I'm running MacOS Ventura 13.4.1.

I have noticed that when I am in full screen (in apps such as google chrome), I don't see banner notifications. If I do get notifications during these times, I only notice once I exit full screen mode and check my dock.

My settings for all notifications are set to 'on' on the apps for which I don't see notifications.

Is there any way of making my apps show banner notifcations in full screen?